# Customize Google AdSense Embedded Connect widget in ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, adsense, adsense-api

Is there any documentation or anywhere that notes how to customize the
AdSense for Platforms [Embedded Connect Widget](https://developers.google.com/adsense/platforms/transparent/embedded-connect#step_5_implement_the_embedded_connect_javascript_library)?

Or have any docs to `adsenseEmbeddedConnect.init()` function?

If i want to get just connect button function with response. Is this possible? How is it done?

Answer (score 0):

There's no separate reference documentation for the `adsenseEmbeddedConnect.init()` method, but [the sections just below the one you pointed at](https://developers.google.com/adsense/platforms/transparent/embedded-connect#step_5_implement_the_embedded_connect_javascript_library) document all the existing function parameters.

Right now, there's no way to customize the appearance of the widget, or the text shown within (other than the display language, via the `hl` query parameter).